# More spawners you place the spawn rate goes down?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-towny

Is it true that if you add more spawners to a base in towny that the spawn rate will go down overall?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, got Towny confused with a Dwarf-Fortress like game with a similar name, wasn't thinking of the Minecraft mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, spawn rates will not go down.  However, if you place the spawners on land that isn't flattened, then that might affect the spawning rate.  You should set the spawners at least 1 or two blocks away, although right next to another works too.

Answer (score 1):

Spawn rates will not go down, but there is a nearby mob cap, so it will stop at a certain number of mobs. To avoid that either kill the mobs or move them away from the spawners.